# SqlJocky to connect to MySQL in Dart: Error 1156 Got packets out of order

Tags: mysql, dart

I'm attempting a quick prototype to see how feasible it would be to replace a current PHP web app with a dart app.  We're using a MySQL database, so I'm checking out SQLJocky.  However, when I run the I get a " Error 1156 (08S01): Got packets out of order" Message.

I haven't done much yet, so I'll list it all.

1. Created new Command line application in Dart Editor
2. Added SQLJocky to Pub and used Pub Get
3. In main used the following Example code with variables different for our database (and different sql)

   var pool = new ConnectionPool(user:user, password:password, port:port, db:db, host:host);
   pool.query('select * from tablename').then((result) {
     for (var row in result) {
       print("A row:");
       for (var col in row) {
         print(col);
       }
     }
   });

That's all I've done!  I'm hoping that means the fix might be quick.  Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think it might be a problem with your MySQL version, which do you use? You could take a look for the error message on google: Looks like it's a confguration problem, might be the problem in your case, too. https://bugs.launchpad.net/myconnpy/+bug/380528

Comment: @Fox32: Looks like we are on version '5.5.25a-cll'.  The database is working fine from the original application, its just this new access that is having issues.  I examined the link you provided and am having trouble finding the options file.  However it looks as if that issue was in a version earlier than what we are using, so if it was the old password issue that should be reflected in the error message right?

Comment: Probably the author of the package can help you. He think he is active on the Dart Misc mailing list.

Comment: I filed an issue: https://github.com/jamesots/sqljocky/issues/31

Comment: I'm the author. Can you turn logging on using the following code, and add the results to the github issue (making sure your password is removed from the log first)?

    hierarchicalLoggingEnabled = true;
    Logger.root.level = Level.ALL;
    Logger.root.onRecord.listen((LogRecord r) {
      print("${r.time}: ${r.loggerName}: ${r.message}");
    });